how to create a new column with a calculated relationship?
I want to create a new column with a calculated relationship, but not a set relationship in power bi.
For example, I have two tables
Table A contains a days in 2000 - 2050 using calendar(2000, 2050)
Table B contains the change of Summer Time every year.
In my application Summer Time marks the new year rather than 1st Jan. I want to add a new column for the summer time day for each day. So YEAR(TableA[Date]) is not exactly that year.
So I first create a new column to check if the current day is after the summer time of that year
'Year to compare' = YEAR(TableA[Date])

Then I associate the relationship with YEAR[TableB[SummerTimeStartDate])
then I want to add a new column
’Reset Year‘ = IF(DATEDIFF(TableA[Date], TableB[SummerTimeStartDate))， [Year to compare]-1, [Year to compare])

Then, I want to add a new relationship between the new 'Reset Year' to TableB, powerbi won't add me.
and I don't know the syntax calling Related(SummerTimeStartDate(where year - 1))
sorry, a clumsy question. how to achieve what I want?

I don't know if this is the case, but you can create an inactive relation between the two table and use USERELATIONSHIP ( <ColumnName1>, <ColumnName2> ). You can read more about in this link

i think this ticket can be closed. i found that DAX is complete a wrong approach. The right way is this should be dealed with power query
